# Images not showing on Wordpress custom page template

Tags: php, image, wordpress, templates

this is the faulty page with images not coming up, http://kokas.x10.mx/?page_id=64

I created a file called sharing-page.php, placed it under my active theme and then applied it to a page. I also placed an images folder at the same level as the php file. My image tags are like this `<img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />`, but something is wrong obviously.

content of the sharing-page.php file

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Sharing
*/
?>
```

```
<div id='page-wrap-sharing'>
    <header>
        <h1>Nodig je vrienden uit</h1>
        <h2>Nodig je vrienden uit en verdien geld bij elke verzoek.</h2>
    </header>
    <div id='main-content-sharing'>
        <section id='share-buttons'>
            <h3>Sociale netwerken</h3>
            <h4>Stuur een uitnodiging naar al je vrienden op sociale netwerken.</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://fray.it" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a></li><!-- Facebook -->                
                <li><a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http://fray.it" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a></li><!-- Twitter -->
                <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://fray.it" target="_blank"><img src="images/google.png" alt="Google" /></a></li><!-- Google Plus -->
                <li><a href="mailto:?Subject=Welcome to Fray&Body=I%20saw%20this%20and%20thought%20of%20you!%20 http://fray.it"><img src="images/email.png" alt="Email" /></a></li><!-- Email -->
            </ul>   
            <p>We delen je contacten met niemand zonder jou toestemming.</p>
        </section>
    </div>  <!-- END main-content -->
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: does images/facebook.png exist in the same folder or should it be in wp-content/themes/blah/image/facebook.png

Comment: @Anigel I found no images folder under the twenty twelve theme, so I placed my own with the images in it, however they don't get picked up

Comment: src="images/twitter.png" should be src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/facebook.png

Comment: You should really [create a child theme](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-create-child-theme?replies=4) and put your image folder in there instead of changing stuff directly inside the twenty-twelve folder

Comment: correct it for all sources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `images` folder is in your theme directory root: `wp-content/themes/yourtheme/images/`, Use `get_template_directory_uri()`

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/facebook.png" 
    alt="Facebook" />
```

Comment: I have placed all this inside a child theme now and got it broken again. Is there another function to get the child theme directory?

Comment: Is it ok? you should be careful. This function `get_template_directory_uri()` points to `wp-content/themes/yourtheme/` directory. Adjust your images or other files with correct path from here.

Comment: The badly-named "get_stylesheet_directory_uri" is the one you normally want to use instead. Official docs note that this is the way to get something that will be correct BOTH for normal themes AND for child themes: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this:

```
 <?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/file_name.*
```